# How to include a jQuery plugin with <script> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm a beginner at JavaScript/jQuery, and I am stuck trying to get this to work. I'm trying to use jQuery [mailcheck](https://github.com/mailcheck/mailcheck) plugin with the example provided in the readme.

I attached the script to HTML file at the end of the code.

```html
<script src="/js/mailcheck.js"></script> <!-- here is a plugin -->
<script src="/js/jquery-3.6.1.js"></script>
<script src="/js/script.js" defer></script> <!-- here is my main script -->
<script src="/js/form.js" defer></script> <!-- here is my below script -->
```

This is my HTML

```html
<nav class="formstyle">
    <label for="email">e-mail
        <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="trass@gmail.com" required>
    </label>                       
    <div id="suggestion"></div>
</nav>
```

And this is what my script looks like. (form.js)

```js
$('#email').on('blur', function() {
  $(this).mailcheck({
    domains: domains,                       
    secondLevelDomains: secondLevelDomains, 
    topLevelDomains: topLevelDomains,        
    suggested: function(element, suggestion) {
      // callback code
      $('#suggestion').html('Did you mean? ' + suggestion.full)
      // console.log(suggestion)
    },
    empty: function(element) {
      $('#suggestion').html('')
    }
  });
});
```

And i got error

```
form.js:59 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).mailcheck is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (form.js:59:11)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.6.0.js:5430:27)
    at elemData.handle (jquery-3.6.0.js:5234:28)
```

What am I doing wrong?

(I have to use jQuery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<script>` tag for the plugin needs to come after the `<script>` tag for jQuery. Like this:

```js
var domains = ['gmail.com', 'aol.com'];
var secondLevelDomains = ['hotmail']
var topLevelDomains = ["com", "net", "org"];

$('#email').on('blur', function() {
  $(this).mailcheck({
    domains: domains,                       
    secondLevelDomains: secondLevelDomains, 
    topLevelDomains: topLevelDomains,        
    suggested: function(element, suggestion) {
      // callback code
      $('#suggestion').html('Did you mean? ' + suggestion.full)
      // console.log(suggestion)
    },
    empty: function(element) {
      $('#suggestion').html('')
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mailcheck@1.1.1/src/mailcheck.min.js"></script>

<nav class="formstyle">
    <label for="email">e-mail
        <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="trass@gmail.com" required>
    </label>                       
    <div id="suggestion"></div>
</nav>
```