# I am trying to use mailcheck, but it doesn't show suggestion for me

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

for some reason it doesn't work, but I am sure that javascript file works, I tried to do everything as in this working example: [How to include a jQuery plugin with <script> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74414921/how-to-include-a-jquery-plugin-with-script-tag) one thing that is different that for me jquery script inside package.json and yarn.lock file

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mailcheck@1.1.1/src/mailcheck.min.js"></script> 
<nav class="formstyle"> 
<label for="email"> e-mail 
<input id="email" name="email" placeholder="trass@gmail.com" type="text">/</input> 
</label> 
<div id="suggestion"></div> 
</nav>
```

my javascript file:

```
const domains = ['gmail.com', 'aol.com'];
const secondLevelDomains = ['hotmail'];
const topLevelDomains = ['com', 'net', 'org'];

$('#email').on('blur', function () {
  'use strict';

  $(this).mailcheck({
    domains: domains,
    secondLevelDomains: secondLevelDomains,
    topLevelDomains: topLevelDomains,
    suggested: function (element, suggestion) {
      // callback code
      $('#suggestion').html(`Did you mean? ${suggestion.full}`);
      // console.log(suggestion)
    },
    empty: function (element) {
      $('#suggestion').html('');
    },
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ok seems that my problem is with `$('#email').on('blur', function ()` that line of javascript code doesn't respond